# Multiple hosts/per app host/dynamic hosts file, Android

Tags: android, root, hosts, tasker, sonos

I have one app in particular (Sonos Controller) that doesn't work well with custom hosts files that are large in size 9+ MB.
Other apps eg. eBay app relies on some internal adnetwork lookup and therefore doesn't even load.

So the question is, can you force a certain app in some way to use a specific hosts file? Maybe via symlinking or a firewall?

At the moment I have set up Tasker to copy a temporary clean hosts file to \etc\hosts while the app loads.
On exit, Tasker will restore the custom hosts file.
This works, but seems like a rather crude way to do it.

EDIT: The reason Sonos Controller app is not working well with custom hosts file, is that it does lookups in the hosts file every time you click on anything.

Comment: And why, exactly, are you trying to override DNS resolution?

Comment: Because every action, even the small ones in the Sonos app does a lookup in the hosts file. This causes the app to hang. When you e.g. type in text to search, the app hangs with every letter inserted in the search bar.